# How to center text on a line

Tags: matlab

I would like to have a string of text that's centered on a line. I've tried this:

```
figure
axis([0,10,0,10])
d = 2.81;
center = 5;
line([center - d,center + d],[5,5])
th = text(center,4.9,'mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm');
set(th,'HorizontalAlignment','center')
```

[image: text is not centered on line]

The text is aligned with the line on the right but not on the left. The above image is a screen shot. I did not consistently have this problem in saved versions of the figure.

Is there a way to center text on a line?  I am not concerned about resizing the figure right now, but I would like to use the default font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it's not possible to position text arbitrarily precise. I tried getting size of text and drawing line and re-positioning text accordingly. More about text properties [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text_props.html).

```
str1 = 'mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm';
center = 5;
text_line_spacing = 0.2;

figure
axis([0,10,0,10])

% Set text initialy
th = text(0,0,str1);

% Get size of text
ext = get(th, 'Extent');  
% text_width = ext(3);
% text_height = ext(4);

% Draw appropriate line
left = center - ext(3)/2; 
right = center + ext(3)/2;
line([left right], [5 5])

% Reposition original text
set(th, 'Position', [left 5+text_line_spacing]);
```